# need help getting xpath for i tag in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, tags

I am trying to get the xpath for the following code but can't seem to figure it out.

```
<i class="icon icon-button-follow pointer action-button js-follow-unfollow-button" data-type="follow" data-id="3470861"></i>
```

Comment: XPATH is relative to the entire page, not just one element. With what you provided, we aren't able to help. We will need more context on the page and what you're attempted use is. I can tell you that PROBABLY the XPATH for that element could be `//i[@data-id="3470861"]`, but that might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand: what does xpath is? Which goal it has? Xpath is a locator, which you can to use to separate one elements and another one. 
I can recommend to you this http://practicalsqa.net/xpath-brainteasers-and-exercises/ class to better understanding this question.
In you case xpath may be for ex.:

```
 //i[@class="icon icon-button-follow pointer action-button js-follow-unfollow-button"]
```

or

```
//i[@data-type="follow"]
```

You have to use something what is unique for this element.

Answer (score 0):

I depends why you want that node, right?

> > //i[@data-id="3470861"]

should find it.  But will you always have that id?